# React native maps marker with custom icon

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-maps

i'm trying to add a custom icon to markers, as far as i tested, when i pass icon prop to , it shows image as i need(The point is, that i want a icon, not image, where i need to provide href(uri)). I'm using Mapview from react-native-map-clustering and Marker from react-native-maps. When i pass a <Icon / > Inside a marker, it shows image for only one marker. Looking forward on help :)

There is my Marker comp.

```
 <Marker tracksViewChanges={true} key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinate} type={marker.type} centerOffset={{ x: 0, y: -20 }} >
                <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap, opacityStyle]}>
                  <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                  <Icon
                  key={index}
                  size={3}
                  reverse
                  reverseColor='black'
                  name='wifi'
                  type='font-awesome'
                  color='#fff'
                  />
                  <View style={styles.marker} />
                </Animated.View>
              </Marker>
```

Is it even possible to get an Font Awesome icon in marker properly?

Comment: Anyone can help with this?

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the code you made so far?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is how I handle my icons as markers. However I don't know if you want the clustering marker to be an icon too, if so I am looking for that as well.

```
<Marker
      key={index}
      coordinate={{ latitude: charger.geolocation.latitude, longitude: charger.geolocation.longitude }}
      onPress={() => this.getMarkerLocation(charger.geolocation.latitude, charger.geolocation.longitude, index, charger)}
    >
    <Icon
        reverse
        size={10}
        name='plug'
        type="font-awesome"
    />
</Marker>
```